# Can you undeploy applications from JETTY?

Tags: jetty

I cant seem to find a way to undeploy or turn off an application whilst JETTY is running. Is the only way to kill JETTY and all other apps running?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944313/smooth-redeployment-of-war-in-production

Comment: It also seems like some place multiple instances of JETTY into a load balancer, and then remove them from the LB when needing to update a .war file. Meaning also that you should design your apps to be stateless.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a few ways.

If you have the `deploy` module enabled, just move the `{appname}.war` (or `{appname}.xml`) out of your `${jetty.base}/webapps/` directory, that will undeploy that webapp.

Another choice is to have JMX enabled and just `.stop()` the webapp in question.