# WAR running after deleting from Webapps in Jetty

Tags: jetty, war, jgroups

I am running JGroups application as WAR file in Jetty 9.2. It joins as first node in the cluster. When I delete war file the cluster instance keeps running. When I redeploy same War file, this war file joins as second node [My expectation - Upon deletion of War file, The first node should die and upon redeploying it again it should start as first node].

Is this happens with Jetty or JGroups?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `deploy` module enabled, removing the war file (and any associated context xml file) from your `${jetty.base}/webapps` directory will undeploy the webapp from Jetty. If you have JMX enabled you can also stop it using that as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870680/can-you-undeploy-applications-from-jetty).

As for the nodes, my guess is that is a JGroups issue. I just wanted to clear up the Jetty behavior.